# ElasticSearch - Daily index mapping

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

Let's say i have an `Index` and I am want to create a daily index with an aliases.

Then I have some application that works against the elastic search(Mostly adding new documents to the index) and I am using `Kibana` to view and query against it.

So option number one for me is to have some separate `Job` which will run daily and create the index with its mapping and daily aliases. My problem here is that now my application is dependent on some outside job.

Option number two is before every insert to the `ElasticSearch` to check whether the Index exists(and if the mappings are current) and if not - to create it. Which seems to me worst then option 1 because of the overhead.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an **index template** which will help you create the index on daily basis with your defined or dynamic mapping.

so on daily basis, the index should get created with some pattern like

index-logging-20180918
index-logging-20180919

You can use some pattern to name your index index-logging-*

And you can add the index in an alias using a similar regex pattern.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html